# Magento Reindex Cron Job is frozen (running for 10 days) - How do I find the name of the process and kill it?

Tags: php, magento, ssh, cron, reindex

I use pagodabox coupled with Magento. In Magento, reindex hasn't been running and it seems that a reindex has frozen upon inspection of the logs (10 days). I am SSHed into the server, but ps -A/ps -e doesn't bring up any processes with a time of greater than 0:21. How do I locate the reindex job which has been running for 10 days?

Comment: hmm. it's just a php function, so it's not "frozen".  could you paste some of the log? it's probably trying to run the same php and gets messed up.  if that's the case, check your apache logs for specific errors when cron is run.

Comment: Here is a pic of the magento panel. Where is the apache log typically located on the server? http://puu.sh/jwE3I/2c28236ea2.png

Comment: assuming a typical LAMP set up, try /var/logs/ or might be in with your vhost stuff (where your actual files are, but a directory lower).

Comment: I'd suggest clearing /domain/var/locks/* and then checking the admin panel. In all likelihood, the process did crash, and the lock has remained in place causing Magento to assume the process is still running.

Comment: Frozen for the time until php timed out which is way sooner than 10 days. You have a lock file sitting around from the failed reindex.